# Visualization Chart or table hidden when dragging or sorting Jquery Portlet

Tags: jquery-ui, google-visualization

I have Google visualization Charts and tables inside each Jquery Portlet with sorting option. When i drag a Portlet from aposition to other position, the visualization charts or table inside portlet will hide. 
I search on google, got http://forums.openflashchart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=824. In that, someone said this problem is solved, but i am not able find the solution. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google visualization Chart options add **'forceIFrame': false**. Now It works fine without hiding chart when dragging portlet.